# Turning column of list of lists (of unequal length) into separate variable columns (python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I'm having trouble turning a column of lists of lists into separate columns. I have a bad solution that works by working on each row independently and then appending them to each other, but this takes far too long for ~500k rows. Wondering if someone has a better solution.

Here is the input:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> pd.DataFrame({'feat': [[["str1","", 3], ["str3","", 5], ["str4","", 3]],[["str1","", 4], ["str2","", 5]] ]})
```

|  | feat |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [[str1, , 3], [str3, , 5], [str4, , 3]] |
| 1 | [[str1, , 4], [str2, , 5]] |

Desired output:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'str1': [3, 4], 'str2': [np.nan,5] , 'str3': [5,np.nan], 'str4': [3,np.nan]})
```

|  | str1 | str2 | str3 | str4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | NaN | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | NaN | NaN |

Update: Solved by @ifly6! Fastest solution by far. For 100k rows and 80 total variables, the total time taken was 8.9 seconds for my machine.

Comment: Why are there all these empty strings in your lists?

Comment: @ifly6 Just part of the data, not really sure why. It's not of primary importance but I included it just for completeness' sake.

Comment: To sum up, the algorithm that is fast on small dataset may not be the same on large datasets.. Thanks to all answers and measuring the time taken!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading your `df`, create `df1` as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.explode('feat').values.flatten()).replace('', np.nan)
df1.index = df.explode('feat').index
```

Set index on `df1` from the original data to preserve row markers (passing `index=df.explode('feat').index` does not work). (Alternatively, to get to the point where you have separated the lists into columns, you could use `df.explode('feat')['feat'].apply(pd.Series)`. I prefer, however, to avoid `apply` so use the DataFrame constructor instead.)

Reset index on `df1` then set multi-index (cannot set the column 0 index directly because it overwrites the original index):

```
df1.reset_index().set_index(['index', 0])
# df1.set_index(0, append=True)  # alternatively should work
```

Then unstack. You can drop columns that are all `NaN` by appending `.dropna(how='all', axis=1)`, yielding:

```
>>> df1.reset_index().set_index(['index', 0]).unstack().dropna(how='all', axis=1)
         2               
0     str1 str2 str3 str4
index                    
0      3.0  NaN  5.0  3.0
1      4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
```

This solution also largely avoids hard-coding which specific columns to look at or move about.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. And by far the fastest solution. I appreciate your help -- it was super instructive to go through each step and print out the intermediate outputs to understand what was going on. Many thanks again

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# explode the list to rows

df=df.explode('feat')

# remove the [] from the list, and split on ","
df[['col1','col3','col2']]=df['feat'].astype('str').replace('[\[\]]','', regex=True).str.split(',', expand=True)

# use pivot after reindexing
df=df.reset_index()
df.pivot(index='index', columns='col1', values='col2')
df
```

```
col1    'str1'  'str2'  'str3'  'str4'
index               
0         3       NaN      5      3
1         4         5    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your nested lists to dictionaries that `pd.Series` can interpret:

```
df = df.feat.apply(lambda val: pd.Series({y[0]:y[2] for y in val}))
df = df[df.columns.sort_values()]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   str1  str2  str3  str4
0   3.0   NaN   5.0   3.0
1   4.0   5.0   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a brute force approach building the new `df1` cell by cell using `df1.loc[i, col_name]`.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'feat': [[["str1","", 3], ["str3","", 5], ["str4","", 3]],[["str1","", 4], ["str2","", 5]] ]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for e in df.loc[i, 'feat']:
        df1.loc[i, e[0]] = e[2]
print(df1)
```

Output (not in column order):

```
   str1  str3  str4  str2
0   3.0   5.0   3.0   NaN
1   4.0   NaN   NaN   5.0
```

And the time taken is

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('''
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'feat': [[["str1","", 3], ["str3","", 5], ["str4","", 3]],[["str1","", 4], ["str2","", 5]] ]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for e in df.loc[i, 'feat']:
        df1.loc[i, e[0]] = e[2]
''', number=10000)

19.209370899999996
```

So it took about 20 seconds for 10K runs. I'm curious to know how the other algorithms perform. Please also run it on your own because time taken varies for *different computers*. And also varies with *different dataset*. Here they are:

#Answer from @ifly6

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('''
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame({'feat': [[["str1","", 3], ["str3","", 5], ["str4","", 3]],[["str1","", 4], ["str2","", 5]] ]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.explode('feat').values.flatten()).replace('', np.nan)
df1.index = df.explode('feat').index
df1 = df1.reset_index().set_index(['index', 0]).unstack().dropna(how='all', axis=1)
''', number=10000)

48.217678400000295
```

#Answer from @Naveed

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('''
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'feat': [[["str1","", 3], ["str3","", 5], ["str4","", 3]],[["str1","", 4], ["str2","", 5]] ]})
df = df.explode('feat')
df[['col1','col3','col2']] = df['feat'].astype('str').replace('[\[\]]','', regex=True).str.split(',', expand=True)
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.pivot(index='index', columns='col1', values='col2')
''', number=10000)

34.94540550000056
```

#Answer from @BeRT2me (it's even faster without rearranging the columns with `df = df[df.columns.sort_values()]`)

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('''
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'feat': [[["str1","", 3], ["str3","", 5], ["str4","", 3]],[["str1","", 4], ["str2","", 5]] ]})
df = df.feat.apply(lambda val: pd.Series({y[0]:y[2] for y in val}))
df = df[df.columns.sort_values()]
''', number=10000)

12.745890199999849
```

Comment: @ifly6 had the fastest time when I increased the number of observations to ~100k. 

I don't know about re-running it n times but at least for one iteration with 100k rows, that was by far the fastest (<5 seconds vs other solutions which are ~1 minute)

Comment: oh i think `for`-loop and `.apply(lambda x)` is computationally heavy for large dataset. Would you post the time taken for 100k rows as an answer please?

Comment: sure, will edit the original! it only took ~9 seconds for me to process 100k rows.